# dayCellDidMount is not calling while clicking day view in fullcalendar Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar-5

dayCellDidMount is calling while week view and month view is clicked. But not calling while day view click. I have to change the background color for some special dates for that I have to get the current cell date and modify the el from dayCellDidMount.